# TYPO3 ods ajaxmail with directmail

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

I need to change the newsletter scubscription status by a checkbox. I need to activate newsletter subscrpition of logged in user with a checkbox. How can it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

depending on your intention two options come to mind:
build a form (or only checkbox) with an eventhandler which acts on click:

1. the page could reload:
   just send the form, change the mode of subscription, redisplay the page with changed status
2. the page should stay: do an AJAX call to change the status, return new status (form) to display

the user could be accessed from the session data.